# How can I find out what level of Trust is needed for EFCodeFirst.SqlServerCompact

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-ce, ef-code-first, trust

I am using in my application DLL [EFCodeFirst.SqlServerCompact](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/EFCodeFirst.SqlServerCompact), installed via Nuget.

In my host (Partial Trust), I get a security error when I try to use this DLL.

How can I find out what level of trust in this DLL?
How can I make it run with Medium/Partial trust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Compact 4.0 supports full and medium trust